# Geometric Brownian Motion and Energy-Efficiency Investments

Tags: brownian-motion, present-value

Suppose the payoff $X$ on an investment follows a Geometric Brownian Motion:
$$
 dX/X = \mu dt + \sigma dz\ ,
$$
for $dz$ an increment of a Wiener process. I wish to compute the expected present value of the payoff
$$
 \mathbb{E}\int_0^\infty X_t e^{-\rho t} dt\ ,
$$
where $\rho$ is the discount rate. Applying Fubini's theorem, and the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X_t]=X_0 e^{\mu t}$, the above evaulates to
$$
 \frac{X_0}{\rho-\mu}\ ,
$$
which accords with my intuition. But since the "random" component of the Brownian motion has disappeared, framework does not really my investment appraisal: I gain no new information than if I would have simply assumed that $X$ were increasing with trend $\mu$.

In the case of an energy-efficiency investment now, if the price of my energy carrier $P$ is modelled as a geometric Brownian motion, I wish to find the optional investment time $T$ such that my return
$$
 \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^T P_t e^{-\rho t} dt + k e^{-\rho T} + \int_T^\infty (1 - \delta) P_t e^{-\rho t} dt \right]\ ,
$$
is maximised (Hassett and Metcalf, "Energy Tax Credits and Residential Conservation Investment", 1995). Here, $\delta$ is the reduction in consumption due to the retrofit.

If I compute out this expression explicitly the variance $\sigma$ disappears just as in the previous case, and the ansatz becomes relatively uninteresting.

I would be grateful for intuition as to if I've made a mistake, or if there is a way to use the properties of Brownian motion to make this investment appraisal more interesting.

Comment: Yes for GBM the mean of $P_t$ depends on the drift $\mu$ but not on volatility $\sigma$ (which affects the variance $Var(P_t)$). This is why $\sigma$ does not appear in your formulas.

Comment: As @fesman has explained, $\sigma$ reflects dispersion, whereas $\mu$ reflects location. For a log-normally distributed random variable $X$ with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, the expectation is $e^{\mu t}$, whereas the variance is $(e^{\sigma^2}-1)e^{2\mu+\sigma^2}$.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw My question is in fact the following: is there any mathematical framework to incorporate this variance into the decision-making process?

Comment: Perhaps you can define your utility from the payoff as $\mathbb{E}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\beta s}u(X_t)ds$ for some concave strictly increasing felicity function $u$. Now risk and $\sigma$ will generally affect your utility.

Comment: @fesman That seems like a promising approach! Would you like to summarise it in an answer? I would be grateful for an example too, if you can provide one.